# couldn't read the name of the user using displayName

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I couldn't read the name of the current loggedin using user.displayName. It gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null`

Code :

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setPosts(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          post: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(user.displayName);
```

By console logging the user `console.log(user)`, i get the information about the current user, but can't just pick only the name of the user.

[image]

I just need to get the current user's name. But `user.display` isn't working as mentioned above.

Comment: can you try using null check   console.log(user?.displayName);

Comment: have you tried of user && user.dislayName or user?.displayName

Answer (score 2):

The time you are logging the name, the user is undefined.
You can use the useEffect hook to subscribe to the [user] variable and listen for changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(user){
        console.log(user.displayName)
    }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: hey, yeah actually i was getting a null user on time of logging in. This solution works. but i would recommend user?.displayName . If you could format the question. I can put a tick mark so that i will help others too .